# What does the concurrency::task destructor do?

Tags: c++, ppl, concurrency-runtime

The [documentation for concurrency::task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/parallel/concrt/reference/task-class?view=msvc-170) says:

> When a task object is assigned to a new variable, the behavior is that of std::shared_ptr; in other words, both objects represent the same underlying task.

So when the `task` is destructed, and no other references remain, what happens to the underlying task?

`ppltasks.h` genuinely does seem to implement this with a `shared_ptr`:

> ```cpp
> template <typename _ReturnType>
> struct _Task_ptr {
>   typedef ::std::shared_ptr<_Task_impl<_ReturnType>> _Type;
>   static _Type _Make(_CancellationTokenState* _Ct,
>                      scheduler_ptr _Scheduler_arg) {
>     return ::std::make_shared<_Task_impl<_ReturnType>>(_Ct, _Scheduler_arg);
>   }
> };
> ```

But what does that mean for usage? Are unnamed temporary tasks OK to use in general? Is this code safe? It seems to continue the task and print `done` after 1 second, even though the task is destructed by the time the print comes around. Is this UB?

```cpp
#include <ppltasks.h>

#include <chrono>
#include <thread>

using namespace std::chrono;
using namespace concurrency;
using std::this_thread::sleep_for;

int main() {
  {
    auto t = create_task([&] {
      sleep_for(1s);
      std::printf("done\n");
    });
  }

  std::printf("sleeping for 2 seconds\n");

  sleep_for(2s);

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: As far as I can tell, a destructed task object basically works like a detached thread. Safe, as long as all its captured references remain valid, and killed/cleaned up by the OS when main() exits.